# How can I make a function call depend on completion of two $http calls in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

In my controller I have the following calls:

```
optionService.init($scope);
optionService.getSubjects1($scope);
optionService.getSubjects2($scope);
optionService.getAbc($scope);
```

Here's the code for the optionService:

```
angular.module('common')
    .factory('optionService',
    ['$http',function ($http) {
        var factory = {
            init: function ($scope) {
                $scope.option = {};
            },
            getSubjects1: function ($scope) {
                var url = '/api/Subject1/GetSelect';
                $scope.loading++;
                $http.get(url)
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.option.subjects1 = data;
                        $scope.loading--;
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.loading--;
                        alert("Error: No data returned from " + url);
                    });
            },
            getSubjects2: function ($scope) {
                var url = '/api/Subject2/GetSelect';
                $scope.loading++;
                $http.get(url)
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.option.subjects2 = data;
                        $scope.loading--;
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.loading--;
                        alert("Error: No data returned from " + url);
                    });
            },
        }
        return factory;

    }]);
```

Is there a way that I could make the call to optionService.getAbc depend on the completion of both the getSubjects1 and getSubjects2 calls? I will also soon be using Angular 1.2 if this makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$q.all(promises)` lets you combine multiple promises in to one:

```
optionService.getAbc = function($scope) {
    $q.all([
       optionService.getSubjects1($scope), 
       optionService.getSubjects2($scope)
     ])
     .then(function() {
       //...
     });
 }
```

**Edit**. Yes, you need to return promises from your `getSubjects` functions. To keep code changes to bare minimum, you could do something like this:

```
optionService.getSubjects1($scope) {
  var url = '/api/Subject1/GetSelect';
  $scope.loading++;
  return $http.get(url)
    .then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.option.subjects1 = data;
      $scope.loading--;
    }, function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.loading--;
      alert("Error: No data returned from " + url);
    });
}
```

With `$http.then()` you create a new promise that can be combined with other promises in `getAbc()`

Comment: This looks good but will I need to do anything to the getSubjects1 and getSubjects2. Do they actually return a promise even if I do not change them?

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite your `getSubject1` and `getSubject2` to return promise. Also passing the `$scope` to the method and updating the scope from the service method is not a good way of doing things. You service methods should return data which assignable in your code. This makes your services more usable and readable.

If you change `getSubject1` and `getSubject2` in lines of

```
getSubjects1: function () {
                var url = '/api/Subject1/GetSelect';
                return $http.get(url);
}
```

In your controller you can do

```
$q.all([
       optionService.getSubjects1(), 
       optionService.getSubjects2()
     ])
     .then(function([data1, data2]) {
       //use data1 to update scope for subject1
       // use data2 to update scope for subject2
       //call any service method.
 });
```